# SAS Macro function input string with a dot character

Tags: sas

I was trying to write this:

```
%ACTUAL_CAL(CQ_20140203,MINUTE15_group0.csv)
```

However, it returns an error:

```
320         MINUTE15_group0.csv
            ___________________
            22
            201
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a name,
              a quoted string.
```

I was wondering why did the CQ_20140203 string went through fine while the latter string returned an error? Is is because of the dot? How should I fix it?

Update:

I plan to use the `MINUTE15_group0.csv` later like this:

```
%MACRO ACTUAL_CAL(DATE_VAR,fname);
DATA TICKERS_NBBO;
    INFILE 'groups/&fname';
    INPUT SYMBOL $;
RUN;
%MEND;
```

Therefore, I think simply surround `MINUTE15_group0.csv` with quotes won't work, as it will also add quotes to my `INFILE` path later.

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with what you have there; it's certainly possible/fine for a dot to be in a macro variable like you describe.  The error you post is unrelated to the macro parameter itself, but is an error caused by whatever that macro parameter is being used by.  You need to show code that is *complete* and will give the error (i.e., if I copy paste directly from the question into a SAS window, it will run and show the error).

Comment: Your example macro should work fine, except it has single `' '` quotes, where it needs double `" "` quotes, to resolve the macro variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out Joe is correct. I should have surrounded a macro variable with double quotation marks instead of single quotation marks.

The following should be correct:

```
INFILE "groups/&fname";
```